# Tableau LOD to find out first date for each field value

Tags: if-statement, tableau-api, level-of-detail

I have a table for `challenge_submissions` -

```
date                       submitter          challenge
8/10/2020 9:02:16 AM         tim              Challenge1
8/10/2020 11:22:04 AM        morty            Challenge2
8/10/2020 11:45:10 AM        morty            Challenge1
8/10/2020 10:18:56 AM        tim              Challenge2
8/10/2020 9:34:14 AM         jim              Challenge3
8/10/2020 12:02:10 PM        pam              Challenge3
```

And another table that matches the players to their teams -

```
team            player
Team A           tim
Team A           pam
Team B           jim
Team B           morty
```

I want a table that shows me which team solved how many challenges first, i.e. something like this -

```
Team            Score    First Solves
Team A           xxx          2
Team B           xxx          1
```

I tried making an LOD for it -

First Solve - `{FIXED [challenge]: MIN([date])}` and then another calculated field
Is First solve - `IF [date] = [First Solve] THEN [First Solve] ELSE NULL END`

and then putting team and submitter in a hierarchy, but that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You reached nearly.

Create an intermediate calc field for easy understanding

`Whether first solved` as

```
If [First Solve date]=[Date] then 1 else 0 END
```

Just to mention I have named first calculated field as `first solve date`

Create your desired field `First solves` as

```
{
FIXED [Team] : SUM([whether first solved])
}
```

You will get your view

[image: Result]

Do tell me if it works.  Upvotes will be appreciated :)

Comment: Hi @AnilGoyal, sorry but this didn't quite work for me. For my current dataset, it always shows me `1` for the whole column.

Comment: Assuming that you have connected both tables, please send me screenshot of your field names/datastructure.  It must work